# Get all Seq logs from requests that meet some condition

Tags: seq-logging

I'm using Seq to capture logs on a local API and I want to find log messages for slow requests.

Each request is writing several logs and one of them includes the total time the request took. I can use something like `RequestTime > 500` to find those logs but it doesn't include the other logs for those requests (understandably). That tells me which APIs are slow but not *why* they're slow, the other logs will provide that information.

Is there a way to ask Seq to return all log messages for requests that meet a condition (like the one for total request time above)? They all have a RequestId value that can be used to identify which logs belong to each request.

I'm aware I can export the results of the first query and use an excel like tool to grab all the request IDs and do an IN clause. I'm looking for a single step option if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no single-step option in Seq for this, today.

Comment: That's unfortunate but it helps to get confirmation so I can stop spending effort looking.  Thanks.